# Oracle Data Integrator Model not showing Tables after Reverse Engineering

Tags: sql-server, oracle-data-integrator

I've created a model in ODI with a SQL Server datastore.

But after successful connection and reverse engineering, I can't see the tables in the SQL Server database.

I've tried adding tables, views and systems tables, nothing showing up, even though there are tables on the SQL Server, and the user has select privileges

I've checked the mask, and I have just % there

I've chosen selective reverse engineering for new datastores and existing datastores.

I don't know what else I'm missing that not bringing up the tables.

Any help here?

Comment: Your title says "Oracle", but your post says "SQL Server", and you have tagged both. What RDBMS are you *really* using, Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: I'm creating a SQL Server datastore on Oracle Data integrator

Comment: How are you looking at the content of the SQL Server database? e.g.: SQL Server Management Studio does not refresh dynamically, you have to right-click on the database's Tables folder and select Refresh to see newly created tables.

Comment: On the Selective Reverse-Engineering tab, did you select the Objects to Reverse Engineer checkbox? It's only after selecting it that your list of tables/views will show up

Comment: Yes @JeromeFr I selected the Reverse Engineering tab. But tables still aren't coming up

Comment: @DavidMakinde did you select the "Objects to Reverse Engineer" checkbox?

Comment: Yes i did @JeromeFr

Comment: Up till today I'm still on it. It still doesn't display any tables, even though the connections and every other thing works fine

Comment: @DavidMakinde - Are you using the standard Reverse-Engineering or did you specify "RKM MSSQL" as an RKM? I would suggest the latter. Also be aware the connection user must have SELECT privileges on any INFORMATION_SCHEMA views as per the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odikm/microsoft-sql-server.html#GUID-EBD2102E-A7EB-49FC-A081-7C498864517A